# How to use overloaded [] in same file C++

Tags: c++, overloading

So I have this function

```
template<class KEY,class T, bool (*tlt)(const KEY& a, const KEY& b)>
T BSTMap<KEY,T,tlt>::put(const KEY& key, const T& value) {
      if (!has_key(key))
          throw KeyError("BSTMap::put");
      this[key] = value;
      ++mod_count;
      return this[key];
}
```

Which is supposed to use my overloaded [], as seen in this code.

```
T& BSTMap<KEY,T,tlt>::operator [] (const KEY& key) {
    if (has_key(key))
        return find_key(map, key)->value.second;
    find_key(map, key)->value = Entry(key, T());
    used++, mod_count++;
    return find_key(map, key)->value.second;
}
```

Essentially, the `[]` operator in this case takes a KEY and creates the entry if it doesn't exist, otherwise it returns a reference to the existing value in that area. My question is then, how do I use the overloaded `[]` operators within the file in order to modify my data. I tried using `this[]`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official name of the method is `operator[]`, so you can use that directly:

```
return operator[](key);
```

You can also dereference `this` to make a reference:

```
return (*this)[key];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I was using this->[] but it looked funky and didn't work as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer, presumably `(*this)[key]` would be legal by dereferencing first, then indexing.